# Timeout in Shell Script

Tags: bash, lsof

Using Shell Script like below:

if [[timeout 60 | wsof -l]]; then
echo "thread sleeping for 60 seconds"
exit
else
echo "timeout failed"
exit
fi

But getting error timeout failed. How to apply timeout for 60 seconds so that return is echo "thread sleeping" in this case? I'm using bash script for this Case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `|wsof -l` is supposed to do, but it may not be working properly because of the brackets (it doesn't work for me when I do it with brackets, but when I do it without it only errors out at the wsof -l command, which I assume you made).

Comment: If you don't want it to display the time then use `timeout /t 30 > NUL`. If you don't want it to be stopped by user input, use `timeout /t 30 /nobreak`.

Comment: no i want to use lsof in conjunction with timeout. how to do that??

Comment: Try switching it to `[[timeout /t 60 |wsof -l]]` instead of `[[timeout 60 |wsof -l]]`

Comment: sure will try and post the output. Thanks, maxbear

Comment: Hi Maxbear, should i declare timeout variable elsewhere in the script ??

Comment: Getting error timeout: command not found for statement [[timeout /t 60 |wsof -l]]

Comment: Actually, timeout 60 should work fine; I think it was the brackets that was messing it up. (Although, I'm assuming wsof -I is something you made). What does it do?

Comment: If it worked, just accept the answer (click the checkmark), you need 15 rep to upvote something.

Comment: hi @maxbear, can i write the above as if timeout 60 lsof | wc -l ; then echo "successful" else echo "not successful" fi